# Why does Rust expects an OK struct in Err in match?

Tags: rust

So I have a following code that basically does a HTTP request using `hyper` library. Afterwards it decodes the json sent by the server. However, in `Err(err) => {...}`, Rust throws `expected struct User, found ()`. Why does Rust expects a User struct to be returned in `Err(err) => {...}`?

```
use hyper::body::Buf;
use hyper::Client;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"
        .parse()
        .unwrap();

    let user = match fetch_json(url).await {
        Ok(data) => data,
        Err(err) => {
            println!("Some error occured {}", err);
            // expected struct User, found ()
        }
    };
    // print users
    println!("users: {:#?}", user);
}

async fn fetch_json(url: hyper::Uri) -> Result<User, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    let client = Client::new();

    // Fetch the url...
    let res = client.get(url).await?;

    let response_code = res.status();

    // asynchronously aggregate the chunks of the body
    let body = hyper::body::aggregate(res).await?;

    // try to parse as json with serde_json
    let user = serde_json::from_reader(body.reader())?;

    Ok(user)
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct User {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
}
```

Comment: It expects the *output* to be of type ``User``, not the input. Basically, your two branches have different return type and Rust expects them to be the same.

Comment: But the return type is `Result<User, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>`. Why does Rust expects the type to be `User`? @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does Rust expects a User struct to be returned in Err(err) => {...}

> But the return type is `Result<User, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>`

But it's not. Your `Ok` match arm returns `data`, which is `User`. So this has become the inferred type for `user` in `let user = match fetch_json(url).await`. That's why the compiler expects the same type to be returned from all other match arms too. You could provide an explicit type annotation to `user`, but that will only get you different errors until you fix the problem: inconsistent return types from match arms.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Rust. But how come it thinks that? Shouldn't the `Err` be different than `Ok`? @SergioTulentsev. How do I fix this?

Comment: "How do I fix this" - obviously, return the same type from all arms. Could be `Option<User>`, for example. Or use never-returning calls, like `panic!`, but this will crash your program if there's an error, naturally.

Comment: Clarified my answer.

Comment: I don't want `panic!` in production application. For example in a HTTP server, I would want to log the error and return 500 or something like that.

Comment: Do just that, then. In this toy example, you could move the `println!("users: {:#?}", user)` into the `Ok` handler directly.

Comment: I could do that but that will make the code will look "nested".  I mean if it's `OK` then I should write all my logic inside `OK` I guess? I am looking for a simple way to handle errors like `let user = call_fn(); if(user.error) {return;} println!(user);` You know what I mean?

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. Looks like you'll love the question mark operator on your Results: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/#the-question-mark-operator-

Comment: Exactly that will be the case. But how do I catch the error so that I can return a 500? Like I could do `let fn = fetch_json(url).await?; if(fn.error /* somehow I know there's an error */) {//catch error}` That I don't understand. I tried doing it with `match` but it complains `User` struct to be returned. Or am I missing something here? I am sorry I am confused. It's just that I am new to rust.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232583/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-damon).

Comment: @Damon You just need to do `return Struct500::new()` in your Err branch. You need to understand that `match` expression MUST have same result type in all arms. `return` expression has type `!` (aka `never`) which coersed to any type.